# Strange jQuery error .children(...).attr(...).change is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I appreciate this may not be a great question, but I'm at my wits end (if the question needs deleting, let me know)

I've installed a plugin in Magento (Zetaprints Web To Print) and the image uploading portion of this plugin doesn't work. I've contacted their support, but they don't want to know about it unless I cough up money.

I think it's due to JavaScript errors being thrown, in both the Firefox and Chrome consoles I get error messages:

Chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'change'

Firefox

> TypeError: $td.children(...).attr(...).change is not a function

I'm not an expert with jQuery or JavaScript by any means, but it seems to me that it's because the object being referenced is not a jQuery object, but something else (quite what I'm not sure). The code that the error is referencing is as follows:

```
  function add_image_to_gallery (guid, url, on_image_load) {
    var trs = $('.tabs-wrapper > .user-images > table > tbody > tr');

    $(trs).each(function () {
      var $tr = $(this);
      var $template = $tr.children('.zp-html-template');

      var $td = $template
                  .clone()
                  .removeClass('zp-html-template')
                  .insertAfter($template);

      // THE CODE BELOW IS THROWING THE ERRORS
      $td
        .children('.zetaprints-field')
        .attr('value', guid)
        .change({ zp: zp }, image_field_select_handler);

      $td
        .children('.image-edit-thumb')
        .click(thumbnail_edit_click_handler);

      var $thumb = $td.children('.image-edit-thumb');

      $thumb
        .find('> .buttons-row > .zp-delete-button')
        .click(delete_image_click_handle);

      var $img = $thumb
                   .children('img')
                   .attr('alt', guid)
                   .attr('src', url);

      if (on_image_load)
        $img.load(on_image_load);
    });
  }
```

(well a small snippet of the code, the file is over 1400 lines long)

Can anybody see anything obviously wrong with the above code? Or does anybody have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If guid is undefined `$td.attr('value')` will return string instead of jquery chain. So 'string'.change will fire error.

```
  $td
    .children('.zetaprints-field')
    .attr('value', guid)
    .change({ zp: zp }, image_field_select_handler);
```

Comment: Good call! It looks like guid is undefined, I'll investigate and see where it gets me

Comment: or you could change it to `$td.children('.zetaprints-field').attr('value', guid); $td.children('.zetaprints-field').change({zp: zp }, image_field_select_handler);`  I am always cautious of the attr function use in chains

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery $ is not fully compatible with magento. I think it has something to do with Prototype.js but I've never looked into it more than "thinking that".  I just know that doing the following fixes your problem...

Any jQuery plugin has to have jQuery().noConflict() enabled.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Basically you have to go through your plugin and replace anywhere there is "$(" with "jQuery("

Comment: I already have `jQuery().noConflict()` in an external file included earlier in the HTML, shouldn't that have solved said problem?

Comment: Or do I still need to go through the file and change somethings?

Comment: You may have used jQuery().noConflict(), but you still have to type out all of the dollar signs as the word jQuery.  That plugin looks like it heavily uses the 'dollar sign' especially in variables. So much so, that at first I thought it was php code!  I'm just saying check into this. Try using the FireBug console and typing jQuery().find('theobjectyouthinkshouldbefound') and see if you get a jquery object back, like the code in your question should work.

Comment: I started a chatroom (Magento). If you want I can help you out.